# Is there any way to get db2 9.1 express without buying IBM support?

Tags: download, db2, installation, db2-luw

Right now I am facing a problem that I have a backup for DB2 9.1 express, but I do not have it, I tried to search the web, and I do not have any luck trying to get the installer and from the IBM sides is the same I am not able to see a link to download this db2 version.

My question is, do you know if there is a way to have the DB2 9.1 express installer without buying IBM support?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to restore 9.1 backup on a 9.7 server, which might be easier to get a hold of.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mustaccio, Yes I know that we could restore the backup on 9.7, but unfortunately the backup should be a offline backup, right now the only backup that I have is an online backup, and well this kind of backup is not able to be restored in 9.7, because of the rollforward nature of the backup .

Comment: Well, tough. I don't think that purchasing support is going to help you, as DB2 9.1 is out of extended support anyway.

Comment: Yes it is out of support, but it says that the ones that are paying support could access old version of DB2 9.1, even I just only need the express edition of IBM, I do not know they are so restrictive with a express edition is not something that you need to pay for, but either way I need to see how I could restore this database, but it seems like there is no any other option.

Comment: Express is something you have to pay for, Express-C (Community Edition) is not.  And Express-C doesn't come with support anyway. Unfortunately, your best bet for getting it is to call IBM and ask nicely :)